# Multiplying Int and Char

Tags: c#

So, I was going over some old code I wrote about 5 years ago for a project. I decided to copy/paste the old code and update the syntax/formatting and whatnot, since it was coded pretty poorly. Then I got to this line:

```
sp += sp3.Substring(sp3.Length - 3, 2) + (Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToChar(sp3.Substring(sp3.Length - 3, 1))) * (Convert.ToChar(sp3.Substring(sp3.Length - 5, 1)))).ToString().Substring(1);
```

I'm guessing it was a typo, but because I don't really understand what's going on here, I can't seem to get the resulting code to function the same way as the original. Oddly enough, even copy/pasting the old code seems to produce different results. That may be unrelated to this code for all I know, but this was the only thing I could find that struck me as odd.

If you don't see what I'm talking about, it seems as though I omitted the conversion back to an integer on the last bit. Honestly I wasn't even aware you *could* multiply an integer and char value together, since I haven't started my .NET classes yet. I tried googling it, to no avail; so if anyone could provide some insight, that would be great. Anyway, all of the "sp" variables are strings with a length > 5.

Comment: A char is simply an integer representing the unicode value of the character. For example `char x = (char)88` or `char x = '\x0058'`

Comment: Your question is to localized and feels like a test.  Why can't you tell us what you expect the code to do?  It is trivial to look at / debug the code and see what it does.  What do you want / need the code to do?

Comment: Haha, no it's not a test. I could post the full code if you like but it's a bit long. Basically what it does is creates a hash code sort of result. @Tejis So, essentially, I can remove all the Convert.ToInt32 from this code, and it'll work the same? I guess the mistake is somewhere else then, but that simplifies the code some. I was aware that a char was a unicode character, but I didn't know they could be directly used as an integer without conversion.

Comment: Ah... hash codes generation is known for looking random.  Remember you are trying to grab different parts and mix them up in randomizing ways.  I would not change anything about it if it is still working.  And if you want to change it write all input test cases before making changes so you don't change the results of your hash.

Comment: It's kind of necessary, because in its current incarnation, it wastes a lot of CPU time doing needless things, like running several foreach loops which could easily be consolidated into a single for loop. When I use the app on slower computers than my own, the performance hit is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the code was written 5 years ago, you may want to revisit what the purpose of the code is and see if you can write it better.  A developer can learn a lot in 5 years.

If you want to better understand what is actually in there, you should break it down into multiple statements and either use the debugger or Console.WriteLine (or Debug.WriteLine) to print out the intermediate values.  This way you can see exactly what each step of the line of code does and how it affects the result.

Another helpful way to get more information is using the Visual Studio Debugger: you can highlight part of the line, right click, then click "Add Watch" to have the debugger evaluate just that sub-expression.  This will also help you try out different inputs to see how it behaves.

Bonus points for writing unit tests for the different inputs and expected outputs to verify the behavior you are expecting.

Comment: Tejs answered my question, while this post helped me fix my mistake. Though I can't uprate, I'll accept this one. The old code had poorly named variables (all the sp's in the original post, haha), and in the process of updating it, I made the mistake of transposing two variables in an equation. I figured this out by using various chunks of text, and noticed that the error only occurred when I added text to both entry points at the same time. There was only one formula in the code that would fail on such an equation, and by reversing the values involved, it worked again.

Comment: Also, this helped me notice a massive flaw in the old design... It allocates a 512 int array, then puts 64 values into the top and 64 into the bottom. Then it reads 128 from the bottom, meaning half the values are 0, and most of the array is wasted space (384 values). Oh well, 5 years is a little late to fix it now since I need it for backward compatibility.